# @Scheduled junit with mockito

Tags: spring, junit, scheduled-tasks

I have service with @Scheduled annotation and i try to test it.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CreatorService {

    private final MyService myService;

    public CreatorService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService= myService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Scheduled(cron = "${test.cron.expression}")
    public void initAndCheckTimers() {
        myService.goToDb();
    }
}
```

and I writed unit-test for this service

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application-default-test.properties")
@EnableScheduling
public class AlertsSchedulerCreatorServiceTest {

        @InjectMocks
        CreatorService service;

        @Mock
        MyService myService;

        @Test
        public void test() throws InterruptedException {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        }
}
```

Mock injected ok, but method initAndCheckTimers() doesn't start. How can I test my @Scheduled method?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't start. You are running a class outside of the spring container, through Mockito and you still expect all the container magic to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that @EnableScheduling only works for @Configuration classes

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html

You can create a Config class like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("com.example.stackoverflow")
public class ScheduledConfig {
}
```

And after add it to your test like this:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(ScheduledConfig.class)
```